# How to pass flags into docker run command in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure, docker, terraform

I am trying to get [tfsec](https://tfsec.dev/docs/usage/) running in my Azure Pipeline. I have been able to get this to run with the following commands without any additional flags:

```
    stages:

    - stage: QualityCheckStage
      displayName: Quality Check Stage
      jobs:
        - job: QualityTestJob
          pool: 
            vmImage: ubuntu-latest
          displayName: Run TFSec
          steps:
            - bash: |
                mkdir TFSecReport
                docker pull tfsec/tfsec:latest
                docker run --rm -v $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory):/src tfsec/tfsec ./src --format JUnit > $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TFSecReport/junit.xml
              displayName: TFSec Static Code Analysis
       
        - task: PublishTestResults@2
          displayName: Publish TFSecReport Test Results
          condition: succeededOrFailed()
          inputs:
            testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
            testResultsFiles: '**/junit.xml'
            searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TFSecReport'
            mergeTestResults: false
            failTaskOnFailedTests: false
            publishRunAttachments: true
```

This operates as I expect and successfully completes the job, checking my terraform code and showing results during the pipeline run.

I would like to add additional tfsec flags such as `--include-passed`, `--verbose`, or `--config-file` to make the pipeline more robust. I am struggling to find a way to pass any of these tfsec flags into the docker run command. I've tried adding the flags to every part of the command and Azure spits out the following error `##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.`.

How can I pass flags into the tfsec image through the docker run command?

Comment: It's `-include-passed`, `-verbose`, with a single dash.

Comment: @jordanm thanks for that. That did get past the Bash error. However, it has now introduced a new problem. I've updated my code above to show the publishing step. Using single dash flags (tested with `-include-passed` and `-verbose` after `./src`) either publishes no results the publish step can find or says `Data at the root level is invalid`. Should the flags be put somewhere else?